# Purchase Order in Quickbooks PHP

Tags: php, quickbooks, purchase-order

How to create a Purchase order in quickbooks? The github Code sample of QB which has helped me to create Invoices does not have a expense order add php file.
I am currently stuck at error code 6440

```
Error code 6440 You must select a product/service or an account for each split line with either an amount or a billable customer
```

Any suggestions or help? It is kind of tiring to figure it out for me now.

Comment: Post your code, or post the XML/JSON you're sending to Intuit. No one can help you without that.